# Python and Pandas: How to make pandas to behavior similarly to numpy.loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a table like this with 12 columns and several lines:

```
 1095         20      27595       14.1      106.4        191          1          0          0          0   6.998509   10.22539  
 1001         32       9958       10.9      -30.6         13          1          0          0          0   6.908755   9.206132  
 1122          9     6125.9       23.5      -16.3         14          1          0          0          0   7.022868   8.720281  
  578         -9      16246        5.9      -25.7        -21          1          0          0          0   6.359574   9.695602
```

If I use `numpy.loadtxt` it works very well. However, I would like to use pandas. I have tried something like this

```
df = pd.read_csv('myFile.txt', sep=" ",header=None)
```

However, it is not working. The error is `pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 90 fields in line 2, saw 92`

Comment: try `df = pd.read_csv('myFile.txt', delim_whitespace=True,header=None)`

Comment: It really worked!! (:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a single space as the separator, you could have done `sep='\s+'` or better is [`delim_whitespace=True`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv), it failed because your txt file is has a varying number of spaces.

```
In [61]:
import io
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
t="""1095         20      27595       14.1      106.4        191          1          0          0          0   6.998509   10.22539  
 1001         32       9958       10.9      -30.6         13          1          0          0          0   6.908755   9.206132  
 1122          9     6125.9       23.5      -16.3         14          1          0          0          0   7.022868   8.720281  
  578         -9      16246        5.9      -25.7        -21          1          0          0          0   6.359574   9.695602"""
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

Out[61]:
     0   1        2     3      4    5   6   7   8   9         10         11
0  1095  20  27595.0  14.1  106.4  191   1   0   0   0  6.998509  10.225390
1  1001  32   9958.0  10.9  -30.6   13   1   0   0   0  6.908755   9.206132
2  1122   9   6125.9  23.5  -16.3   14   1   0   0   0  7.022868   8.720281
3   578  -9  16246.0   5.9  -25.7  -21   1   0   0   0  6.359574   9.695602
```

Or you could have used [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf):

```
In [62]:    
pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(t), header=None)
Out[62]:
     0   1        2     3      4    5   6   7   8   9         10         11
0  1095  20  27595.0  14.1  106.4  191   1   0   0   0  6.998509  10.225390
1  1001  32   9958.0  10.9  -30.6   13   1   0   0   0  6.908755   9.206132
2  1122   9   6125.9  23.5  -16.3   14   1   0   0   0  7.022868   8.720281
3   578  -9  16246.0   5.9  -25.7  -21   1   0   0   0  6.359574   9.695602
```